# Is there a cleaner, more efficient way to have an IF statement that doesn't error on undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I'm checking for nextProps like so:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.invite && nextProps.invite.status) {
    }
  }
```

I need the above because it's possible nextProps.invite is undefined so if I had just `nextProps.invite.status` I would get a JS console undefined error...

Is there a cleaner, more efficient way to write the above logic?

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for - but I see / use this pattern a lot in simple react apps. In something with redux - the conditional checks will probably happen in my reducers / containers before I ever pass the props to my components.

Comment: @ChristopherMesser the one above or did you mean to paste something?

Comment: Yes, what you've shown above.

Comment: `typeof nextProps.invite !== 'undefined'` or have a initial state in your reducer.

Comment: @bergi shure? I think there are better answers at this case, that would be a good *may have a look at* instead of an exact dupe

Comment: @Jonasw It might not have the best answers possible, but it's the canonical duplicate for the topic. Do you have other links in mind?

Comment: @bergi im thinking of a prototype to prevent errors

Comment: Can also write it as `(nextProps.invite || {}).status`

Comment: @Jonasw Well yes not having the property being `undefined` in the first place is usually the best solution, but that's not what was asked for.